# If inline with two actions if true

Tags: javascript

I am creating a clock and trying use if inline, here is the code:

```
h == 24 ? _setWeekDay($this) && (h = 0) : h > 24 ? _setWeekDay($this) && (h -= 24): null;
```

But the problem is when h > 24 the code set week day, but don't subtract h -= 24! Can you explain me why this is not working?

Comment: What does `_setWeekDay()` return? Something truthy?

Comment: doesn't have return

Comment: Try to use inline if only if the operation is simple like D = A ? B : C.
All that stuff only makes the code less maintainable.

Comment: I found the problem, but I don't understand why it happens... if the function has no return if doesn't execute the next statement...

Comment: `undefined` is falsy

Comment: dont' applied the condition to the statement. In this case _setWeekDay($this) && (h = 0) . Just put h=0 in the _setWeekDay function

Comment: @adeneo if `h` is 24, it will execute first block. If it's not 24 and it's greater than 24 it will do the second block, otherwise null. Not sure what you're going on about.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm - Sure, if you say so

Comment: @MatheusMachado If it doesn't have a return defined, that's your problem.

Comment: I do say so? That's how the code is written? Perhaps you're unfamiliar with ternary operators?

Comment: I'm probably just more familiar with code that humans can read ?

Comment: @adeneo perhaps you're a beginner. Ternary is basic and very readable by humans. It's used all over the place. Instead of bringing negativity and incorrect statements to SO posts, maybe familiarize yourself with what's being asked since you clearly have a fundamental misunderstanding of A) what the OP is asking and B) ternary operations

Comment: Thank you all, the answer below solve my question, I thought that to execute 2 actions in if inline I had to use && cause ; generate an error, but I have to use , instead

Comment: @MatheusMachado don't forget to check the answer correct and upvote :)

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm - Sure, I'm a beginner, thanks for showing me how it's done!

Comment: No problemo, kiddo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h == 24 
    ? _setWeekDay($this) && (h = 0) 
    : h > 24 
        ? _setWeekDay($this) && (h -= 24)
        : null;
```

Split up easier for better readability. Your issue is `&&` which is not meant for what you're trying to accomplish. You're using ternary operator which is useful to not make so many if statements. What you need is this:

```
h == 24 
    ? (_setWeekDay($this), (h = 0)) 
    : h > 24 
        ? (_setWeekDay($this), (h -= 24))
        : null;
```

This will allow you to perform multiple actions in a ternary conditional. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kxsecay/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I felt that something was wrong with &&, but you answered my question!

Comment: That's what SO is for :D

Comment: Is there are name for this construct? I see that `(<x>, <y>)` always returns the second expression, in this case `<y>`. @AlGoreRhythm

Comment: It's probably not to be used when you want to return something. You should not have multiple items for that, but if you wanted to do what the OP did and call a function, and then return something, then this would work. "The comma operator creates an expression which is a series of sub-expressions. The sub-expressions are evaluated in order, left-to-right. The value of the overall expression is the value of the rightmost of the sub-expressions. So that line is very...expressive...what with a total of seven* different expressions inside it." http://es5.github.io/#x11.14

Comment: I don't understand how you correlate what `_setWeekDay` does when he didn't post it. With that in mind, clearly, it's irrelevant what the function does. He simply wants to call a function, and then perform the action. Should he do it the method he calls? Yes, but that's not what he asked and there IS a way to do it that way.

Comment: This will only work if `_setWeekDay()` returns a truthy value (which it doesn't do or hasn't done: "_I found the problem, but I don't understand why it happens... if the function has no return if doesn't execute the next statement..._"). And, imho, this looks terrible and should be done with a regular `if...else...`